# Get dictionary values as attributed

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a sample dictionary.

```
>>> my_dict = {'name': 'James', 'age': 10}
```

I want to get attributes from dictionary as following,

```
>>> my_dict.name
James
>>> my_dict.age
10
```

How can I override dict meta methods for this ?
I have dictionary consisting large number of key, values. I just want convert it to some object so that it can work as normal dictionary as well as getting attribute as explained above.

Comment: expected input and output?

Comment: Above question link answers my query.

Comment: ```class attrdict(dict):
         __getattr__ = dict.get```. Solved with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a namedtuple:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> my_dict = {'name': 'James', 'age': 10}
>>> my_dotted = namedtuple('GenericDict', my_dict.keys())(**my_dict)
>>> my_dotted
GenericDict(name='James', age=10)
>>> my_dotted.name
'James'
```

Comment: But then `my_dotted['name']` would fail.

Comment: Yes, i didnt read the last sentence :/